# How to fix " 'int' object has no attribute 'execute' " error in python 3.x using SQLite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

So, I am creating a python code using SQLite database that is stored in the memory. I first wrote this code with the values of the employees already given. Then I made some changes to the code where the user inputs the values that will be stored in the database, but it seems like I am doing something wrong because no matter what I try it still returns the same mistake.

I tried different things. For instance, I tried instead of using the class I created, creating lists where everything is stored. Still the same error. I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import sqlite3
from Employee import Employee


conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE employees( 
                  first text,
                  last text,
                  pay integer
                  )""")
# here I create a table called 'employees'. It stores the first name, the last name and the payment


def insert_emp(emp):  # This is used for inserting employees in the table
    with conn:
      c.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (:first, :last, :pay)", {'first': emp.first, 'last': emp.last, 'pay': emp.pay})


def get_emp_by_name(lastname):  # Searches for all results with the given LAST name
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE last = :last", {'last': lastname})
    return c.fetchall()


def update_pay(emp, pay):  # Updates payment info
    with conn:
        c.execute("""UPDATE employees SET pay = :pay WHERE first = :first AND last = :last""",
                  {'first': emp.first, 'last': emp.last, 'pay': pay})


def del_emp(emp):  # Deletes employee
    with conn:
        c.execute("DELETE from employees WHERE first = :first AND last = :last",
                  {'first': emp.first, 'last': emp.last})




a = input("First name: ")
b = input("Last name: ")
c = int(input("Payment: "))  # Turn the payment into an integer, because input automatically sets the value as a str
emp_1 = Employee(a, b, c)  # Here I try to add the values given by the user in my class that I have created.
insert_emp(emp_1)
emps = get_emp_by_name('Doe')
print(emps)

conn.close()
```

This is what I tried to do, by using the class that I created.

Here is the class:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
```

I also wrote the code with already given values.

Here is the end of the code that is with the given values (It works without a problem):

```
emp_1 = Employee('John', 'Doe', 80000)  # Add the employee, using the class that I have created
emp_2 = Employee('Jane', 'Doe', 90000)
insert_emp(emp_1)
insert_emp(emp_2)

emps = get_emp_by_name('Doe')
print(emps)
update_pay(emp_2, 95000)
del_emp(emp_1)

emps = get_emp_by_name('Doe')
print(emps)

conn.close()
```

If we input, for instance, Gabriel; Doe; 5000;

the result should be:

```
[('Gabriel', 'Doe', 5000)]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But, the result I actually get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File *location*, line 56, in <module>
    insert_emp(emp_1)
  File *location*, line 17, in insert_emp
    c.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (:first, :last, :pay)", {'first': emp.first, 'last': emp.last, 'pay': emp.pay})
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Comment: it looks like `c` is integer number instead of `cursor` so it try to do something like `5.execute(..)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting your cursor `c` with

```
c = int(input("Payment: "))
```

Don't use global variables, and use cursors as short living objects:

```
def insert_emp(conn, emp):  # This is used for inserting employees in the table
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (:first, :last, :pay)", {'first': emp.first, 'last': emp.last, 'pay': emp.pay})
```